# Addition of string fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a column name Amount whose values are sometimes like 400(300) and hence the data type is string in Crystal report.

Now i wish to do summation of Amount Column.How to do that?

the Sum(FieldName) forumla does not work because it is string. I, no way can convert it into numeric..

Let me know if any inputs required.

Thanks..

Comment: What do you want "400(300)" to be converted to? 400? 300? 400,300?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new formula in your report like so:

```
if (IsNull({Testing.Amount}) or not IsNumeric({Testing.Amount}) or {Testing.Amount} = "")
Then 0 
Else
ToNumber({Testing.Amount})
```

And display the formula on the report.

Comment: thanks..again! :-) but toNumber doesn't work. when displaying the formula on report it threws an error message that "the string is not numeric"(when previewing the report)

Comment: @Romil - You must have blanks or alpha characters in the data. I've updated my answer to allow for nulls and blank strings.  Can you confirm if you have any alpha characters in your data?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The values are having blanks and is also having special character such as bracket '(' and ')'. I updated your code, but it shows same error. thanks!

Comment: @Romil - The brackets aren't an issue as they are interpreted as a negative figure.  I've added in a check to ensure it doesn't try to convert any values that contain alpha characters.  This means that a value of `12nk` or `one` will be converted to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Late But as i was stuck at this, so

- Create A New Formula Field (lets say name is 'abc')
- Convert your string column to number in this field
  like so (ToNumber({tablename.yourfield})
- Then create a new Running Total. In this field Select Sum(abc) and place this Running total where you want.